# writing itemloader by item to xml or csv using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a scrapy newbie and have written below spider. I want write to xml or csv with each row in csv or each item in xml as name,tele,addr.

**I am using command:**
scrapy crawl abc -o items.csv -t csv

**I am looking for output:**

```
name,addr,tele
n1,a1,t1
n2,a2,t2
n3,a3,t3
```

**But I get:**

```
name,addr,tele
n1,n2,n3 a1,a2,a3 t1,t2,t3
```

**Spider Code**

```
import scrapy

from abc.items import abcItem
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader

class abcSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "abc"
    allowed_domains = ["abc.com"]
    start_urls = ["abc.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        l = ItemLoader(item=abcItem(), response=response)
        l.add_xpath('name', '//section[@class="abcrp"]/a/@title')
        l.add_xpath('tele', '//p[@class="abcw"]/a/@href')
        l.add_xpath('addr', '//span[@class="dn"]/text()')
        return l.load_item()
```

**items code**

```
import scrapy
class abcItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    addr = scrapy.Field()
    tele = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: Show the relevant page HTML code or share the link to the web page. Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess that you have a problem with line breaks - could it be that your script generates linux line breaks and you view it on a windows machine? Linux linebreaks in Windows just look like white space.

Comment: alecxe, the xpaths are working correctly and I am able to write to csv as well. The problem is that the itemloader is returning all values of a field in 3 lists: name, addr, tele. These lists are written as a single row in 3 csv columns (3 items in case of xml). I need a way to have one row per item. So if there are 10 names, addr and tele, I need 10 rows and not one. Any help?

Comment: alexander, i m doing everything on windows

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this. I used a for loop on a outer tag, that contained my name, addr and tele tags

Comment: Any chance you still have the code for this? I tried to implement a loop myself but it doesn't put it in different rows