# Scrapy: Return Each Item in a New CSV Row Using Item Loader

Tags: python-2.7, csv, scrapy

I am attempting to produce a csv output of select items contained in a particular class (title, link, price) that parses out each item in its own column, and *each instance in its own row* using itemloaders and the items module.

I can produce the output using a self-contained spider (without use of items module), however, I'm trying to learn the proper way of detailing the items in the items module, so that I can eventually scale up projects using the proper structure. (I will detail this code as **'Working Row Output Spider Code'** below)

I have also attempted to incorporate solutions determined or discussed in related posts; in particular:

[Writing Itemloader By Item to XML or CSV Using Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419564/writing-itemloader-by-item-to-xml-or-csv-using-scrapy) posted by [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4743595/sam)

[Scrapy Return Multiple Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46571543/scrapy-return-multiple-items) posted by [Zana Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6206268/zana-daniel)

by using a for loop as he notes at the bottom of the comments section.  However, I can get scrapy to accept the for loop, it just doesn't result in any change, that is the items are still grouped in single fields rather than being output into independent rows.

Below is a detail of the code contained in two project attempts --**'Working Row Output Spider Code'** that does not incorporate items module and items loader, and **'Non Working Row Output Spider Code'**-- and the corresponding output of each.

**Working Row Output Spider Code: btobasics.py**

```
import scrapy
import urlparse

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'basic'
    allowed_domains = ['http://http://books.toscrape.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com//']

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath('//*[@class="product_pod"]/h3//text()').extract()
        links = response.xpath('//*[@class="product_pod"]/h3/a/@href').extract()
        prices = response.xpath('//*[@class="product_pod"]/div[2]/p[1]/text()').extract()

        for item in zip(titles, links, prices):
        # create a dictionary to store the scraped info
            scraped_info = {
                'title': item[0],
                'link': item[1],
                'price': item[2],
            }

            # yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
            yield scraped_info
```

**Run Command to produce CSV: $ scrapy crawl basic -o output.csv**

[Working Row Output WITHOUT STRUCTURED ITEM LOADERS](https://pastebin.com/HQv2kueA)

**Non Working Row Output Spider Code: btobasictwo.py**

```
import datetime
import urlparse
import scrapy

from btobasictwo.items import BtobasictwoItem

from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'basic'
    allowed_domains = ['http://http://books.toscrape.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com//']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Create the loader using the response
        links = response.xpath('//*[@class="product_pod"]')
        for link in links:
            l = ItemLoader(item=BtobasictwoItem(), response=response)

            # Load fields using XPath expressions
            l.add_xpath('title', '//*[@class="product_pod"]/h3//text()',
                        MapCompose(unicode.strip))
            l.add_xpath('link', '//*[@class="product_pod"]/h3/a/@href',
                        MapCompose(lambda i: urlparse.urljoin(response.url, i)))
            l.add_xpath('price', '//*[@class="product_pod"]/div[2]/p[1]/text()',
                        MapCompose(unicode.strip))
            # Log fields
            l.add_value('url', response.url)
            l.add_value('date', datetime.datetime.now())

            return l.load_item()
```

**Non Working Row Output Items Code: btobasictwo.items.py**

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class BtobasictwoItem(Item):
    # Primary fields
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
    price = Field()
    # Log fields
    url = Field()
    date = Field()
```

**Run Command to produce CSV: $ scrapy crawl basic -o output.csv**

[Non Working Row Code Output WITH STRUCTURED ITEM LOADERS](https://pastebin.com/P3HMX7yf)

As you can see, when attempting to incorporate the items module, itemloaders and a for loop to structure the data, it does not seperate the instances by row, but rather puts all instances of a particular item (title, link, price) in 3 fields.

I would greatly appreciate any help on this, and apologize for the lengthy post. I just wanted to document as much as possible so that anyone wanting to assist could run the code themselves, and/or fully appreciate the problem from my documentation. (please leave a comment instructing on length of post if you feel it is not appropriate to be this lengthly).

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your `ItemLoader` to use another `selector`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # Create the loader using the response
    links = response.xpath('//*[@class="product_pod"]')
    for link in links:
        l = ItemLoader(item=BtobasictwoItem(), selector=link)

        # Load fields using XPath expressions
        l.add_xpath('title', './/h3//text()',
                    MapCompose(unicode.strip))
        l.add_xpath('link', './/h3/a/@href',
                    MapCompose(lambda i: urlparse.urljoin(response.url, i)))
        l.add_xpath('price', './/div[2]/p[1]/text()',
                    MapCompose(unicode.strip))
        # Log fields
        l.add_value('url', response.url)
        l.add_value('date', datetime.datetime.now())

        yield l.load_item()
```

Comment: I tried making the modifications to line 5 as you suggest. However, it did not change the output. I also tried variations  such as: ' l = ItemLoader(item=BtobasictwoItem(), selector=links)' and ' l = ItemLoader(item=BtobasictwoItem(), selector=link, response=response)' Am I missing something. Do I need to ammend the code in some other way?

Comment: Thanks so much. I was able to produce the intended output by replacing the code as instructed with an ammendment to the 'return' in the last line with 'yield'. I tried to make an edit to your contribution but created my own error by referring to 'response' instead of 'return'.  Thanks again....very much!

Comment: @dldatacowboy Sorry, I missed this part. Don't forget to accept my answer :-)